# Can PHP filesize() method be spoofed with image metadata?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, metadata, filesize

The php filesize() method is used to determine the size of a file in bytes. One example would be to determine the size of an image file. If the method gets its data from an images metadata, is it possible this could be spoofed by modifying the image metadata somehow, or does the method actually calculate file size based on the true contents of the image file?

```
<?php filesize(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `filesize`

> Returns the size of the file in bytes, or FALSE (and generates an error of level E_WARNING) in case of an error.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

It does not in any way try to interpret image metadata.